# Check if a range is an entire row

Tags: excel, vba

Is there is a statement like

```
if (Range1 contains all columns) then do stuff
```

I need a sub to run when cutting and inserting rows and I have other code running when it is not an entire row.

Comment: Try `If myRange.columns.count = Sheet("Sheet1").Columns.Count`? assuming `myRange` is also on `Sheets("Sheet1")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BruceWayne's suggestions seems logical. Also you can check if yourRange.EntireRow.Address is the same as the entire row address:

```
yourRange.EntireRow.Address = Range(yourRange.Cells(1, 1), yourRange.Cells(1, yourRange.Columns.Count)).Address
```

Comment: BruceWaynes answer worked perfectly but i cant tick a comment

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple way to do it. It will work for multiple entire rows in the given range. To check for columns, simply change "EntireRow" to "EntireColumn".

```
If Range1.Address = Range1.EntireRow.Address
```